# V8 Hello World compilation error: cannot convert from 'v8::Local<v8::String>' to 'v8::String'

Tags: c++, v8

I am new to V8. I was trying to run the Hello World example form [here](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started).

But, I am getting compilation error at this line:

```
v8::String source = v8::String::New("'Hello' + ', World'");
```

`error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'v8::Local<v8::String>' to 'v8::String'`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String class changed. It does not have anymore the New method; it has NewFrom* methods:

```
static Local< String >  NewFromUtf8 (Isolate *isolate, const char *data, NewStringType type=kNormalString, int length=-1)
static Local< String >  NewFromOneByte (Isolate *isolate, const uint8_t *data, NewStringType type=kNormalString, int length=-1)
static Local< String >  NewFromTwoByte (Isolate *isolate, const uint16_t *data, NewStringType type=kNormalString, int length=-1)
```

You can browse the doxygen documentation: http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html#aa4b8c052f5108ca6350c45922602b9d4

A string can be created this way:

```
v8::Isolate* i = v8::Isolate::New();//create an isolate instance
//( if you already have one just get it: GetIsolate() 
//=>http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Context.html
v8::Local<v8::String> constant_name = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(i,"asd");
i->Dispose();
```